# NSAttributedString Strike attribute not working

Tags: ios, text, nsattributedstring, strikethrough

I know this question has been asked many times, but none of the answers I read helped me to fix my problem...

In my iOS app, I'm generating a PDF file using default frameworks (UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile...).
Everything works fine, I can change text colors, underlying styles, etc.

But I don't manage to strike a string.

Here's my code:

```
[toBeConfirmedText addAttributes:@{ NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: @(0), NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleThick), NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor] } range:NSMakeRange(0, toBeConfirmedText.length)];
```

But that does not work...

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should add a comment that your code has no problem in Xcode 10. But because I need to add test codes, so you may treat it as an answer.

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myTest.pdf"];
        BOOL result =    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath, CGRectZero, nil);

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

        NSMutableAttributedString * toBeConfirmedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"mytest"];

        [toBeConfirmedText addAttributes:@{ NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: @(0), NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleThick), NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor] } range:NSMakeRange(0, toBeConfirmedText.length)];

        [toBeConfirmedText drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 200)];
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Comment: Thanks your your answer! I tried your code directly in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and it worked well... I don't know if i'm happy with that, since I really don't see what's wrong in my original code!! Is it possible that's because I'm using Core Text to render my PDF file? I'm encapsulating the attributedString in a CTFramesetterRef...

Comment: Wow! I finally found the solution.. That was because of using CTFramesetterRef... I don't understand what's wrong with that (and to be honest I don't remember why I preferred this way instead of calling -drawInRect: directly), but now that I'm using this method, as you suggest, that works fine. Thank you!